# Why is the minimal pumping length for $(01)^*$ equal to 1?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I see why the minimum pumping length is at most 2 (since 01 can be pumped). But why is this counterexample not valid?

Let $A=(01)^*$ and assume it has pumping lenght $p=1$. Then lets consider the string $01\in A$, since its lenght is greater than 1 it must hold the pumping lemma. But given $p=1$ necessarily $x=\varepsilon, y=0, z=1$ and $xy^2z=001\notin A$. Therefore minumum pumping length must be greater than one and equal or smaller than two.

Comment: There are no strings of length 1 in the language $(01)^*$ therefore every string in $(0,1)^*$ whose length is at least 1 can be pumped.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson yes, but the pumping lemma does not require for $y$ to be on the language, moreover, I can only pump a single character given that $p=1$, so by pumping a single character I get a string outside the language.

Comment: The minimal pumping length of a regular language is the smallest $p$ such that any string in the language whose length is at least $p$ can be pumped.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Yes, but the string $y$ that is being pumped doesn't need to be on the language. Then my question still holds, why is my counterexample not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum pumping length depends on it's definition, there are two forms of pumping lemma. The weaker form says that forall $w$ in language exists $p$ s.t. if $p \leq |w|$ then there exists $x$, $y$, and $z$ s.t. followings hold

- $w = xyz$
- $|y| \geq 0$
- $\forall m, xy^mz \in A$.

With this weak form $p=1$ is enough for $A=(01)^*$, but the second (stronger) form tell us an additional fact which says

- $|xy| \leq p$.

for satisfying this fact we need to change the pumping length, as you could provide counterexample correctly, $p=1$ doesn't satisfies this new fact.